# Matplotlib graphs data wrong from two lists of x and y points

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot

These are the two lists:

```
x = [736297.48567129625, 736297.53253472224, 736297.57858796301, 736297.50894675928, 736297.55557870376]

y = [-757, -706, 385, -247, 126]
```

Here's my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdate

x = [736297.48567129625, 736297.53253472224, 736297.57858796301, 736297.50894675928, 736297.55557870376]
y = [-757, -706, 385, -247, 126]

plt.figure()
plt.plot_date(x, y, fmt='b-')
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

The x list values are converted from epoch time, using mdate.epoch2num(epoch).

This is the graph I get, which is obviously not plotted chronologically:

[Matplotlib improperly plotted chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Np9Ls.png)

**Bonus question:** You can see that the time format on the x axis looks horrible. Any idea how to present it in the format yy-mm-dd-hh-ss?

Thanks to all python gurus for your assistance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pyplot is just plotting in the order you provided your data.
It turns out that `x` isn't sorted so the plot kinda goes "backward".

You should then sort you indices (and its corresponding values) to get what you want:

```
#Sort by date (x) and apply change to values (y) 
xx, yy = zip(*sorted(zip(x, y)))
plt.plot_date(xx, yy, fmt='b-')
```

Giving you the following plot:
[image]

`pltrdy`

---

**Bonus question:**
Have look [here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/date_demo.html) for pyplot dates tick formatting. It may be easy to understand and do what you want.

Comment: Excellent, thank you! Since I'm obtaining these two lists from a dictionary, do you think it will be faster to get the data as [(time, value), (time, value)] and then sort the list, before plotting, versus zipping?

Comment: Not sure to understand your point. If you don't have hugely huge data this may be ok anyway. I usually used library like Pandas or numpy so I don't really what is the best when built in function are involved (because they are not, usually, the best if performance matters)